# Node express JS unable to parse JSON body

Tags: node.js, json, express, body-parser

I am trying to create simple REST API through NodeJS and Express, every thing works fine, but not able to POST JSON data to API. body-parser is not able parse JSON data

```
curl -XPOST -H "Content-type: application/json" 127.0.0.1:3000/contact -d "{'name':'Mazhar'}"
```

and here is the code

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.post('/contact', (req, res) => {
    let body = req.body;
    console.log(body);

    body.message = "Hello " + body.name;
    res.send(body);
});
app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Server is listening on 3000");
});
```

and here is the error, no matter how I change the JSON body its always an error, I tried to put in double quote as well, and with any single or double quote there is always error, as per my understading the applicaiton is not able to parse json data.

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at createStrictSyntaxError (E:\ws-js\nodejs\web-server\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:158:10)
    at parse (E:\ws-js\nodejs\web-server\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:83:15)
    at E:\ws-js\nodejs\web-server\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:121:18
    at invokeCallback (E:\ws-js\nodejs\web-server\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:224:16)
    at done (E:\ws-js\nodejs\web-server\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:213:7)
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (E:\ws-js\nodejs\web-server\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:273:7)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:203:15)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1145:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

> Solution

Ok after apply multiple techniques, finally I realized that in this particular case, single quotes does not work at all, the only solution worked for me was provided by @AfridaAnzum.

Every thing should be in double quotes and all attributes and values should also be enclosed in escaped double quotes "{\"key\":\"value\"}"

I guess this is very poorly written library that is not able to handle the keys with single quote or without quotes.

Comment: send your post request like this `curl -XPOST -H "Content-type: application/json" 127.0.0.1:3000/contact -d "{\"name\":\"Mazhar\"}"`

Comment: Try update your body-parser version

Comment: `{'name':'Mazhar'}` is not valid JSON, that is why it fails.

Answer (score 1):

Because your JSON syntax is invalid:

```
{'name':'Mazhar'}
 ^
 '--------- invalid token '
```

While [JSON](https://www.json.org/) is **inspired** by javascript [object literal syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) it is not the same thing. JSON is a subset of javascript object literal syntax invented by [Douglas Crockford](https://www.crockford.com) when he wanted to use javascript object notation in his project and was told by his managers that he could only use standard protocols. So he wrote a spec for the data format and called it JSON.

The specification for JSON can be found at https://www.json.org

JSON was specifically designed to be stricter than javascript object literal syntax to make it easier to implement in other languages (especially low-level languages like C)

Answer (score 0):

JSON data key value should be kept in double-quotes else you will get parse error. For Example: `'{"name": "Mazhar"}'`
Try running below code:

```
 curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -XPOST http://localhost:3000/contact -d '{"name":"Mazhar"}'
```